# Two Types of settings in WP - The Doubt

Tags: functions, options, settings-api

I was trying to learn some basics of wordpress plugin development, and I stumbled upon two types of settings.

## 1

```
add_settings_field(
    'custom_title',
    esc_html__('Custom Title', 'myplugin'),
    'myplugin_callback_field_text',
    'myplugin', 
    'myplugin_section_login', 
    [ 'id' => 'custom_title', 'label' => esc_html__('Custom title attribute for the logo link', 'myplugin') ]
);

add_settings_field(
    'custom_style',
    esc_html__('Custom Style', 'myplugin'),
    'myplugin_callback_field_radio',
    'myplugin', 
    'myplugin_section_login', 
    [ 'id' => 'custom_style', 'label' => esc_html__('Custom CSS for the Login screen', 'myplugin') ]
);

add_settings_field(
    'custom_message',
    esc_html__('Custom Message', 'myplugin'),
    'myplugin_callback_field_textarea',
    'myplugin', 
    'myplugin_section_login', 
    [ 'id' => 'custom_message', 'label' => esc_html__('Custom text and/or markup', 'myplugin') ]
);

add_settings_field(
    'custom_footer',
    esc_html__('Custom Footer', 'myplugin'),
    'myplugin_callback_field_text',
    'myplugin', 
    'myplugin_section_admin', 
    [ 'id' => 'custom_footer', 'label' => esc_html__('Custom footer text', 'myplugin') ]
);

add_settings_field(
    'custom_toolbar',
    esc_html__('Custom Toolbar', 'myplugin'),
    'myplugin_callback_field_checkbox',
    'myplugin', 
    'myplugin_section_admin', 
    [ 'id' => 'custom_toolbar', 'label' => esc_html__('Remove new post and comment links from the Toolbar', 'myplugin') ]
);
```

## 2

And in some other plugin I find it like this:

```
function paytm_settings_list(){
    $settings = array(
        array(
            'display' => 'Merchant ID',
            'name'    => 'paytm_merchant_id',
            'value'   => '',
            'type'    => 'textbox',
            'hint'    => 'Merchant ID'
        ),
        array(
            'display' => 'Merchant Key',
            'name'    => 'paytm_merchant_key',
            'value'   => '',
            'type'    => 'textbox',
            'hint'    => 'Merchant key'
        ),
        array(
            'display' => 'Website',
            'name'    => 'paytm_website',
            'value'   => '',
            'type'    => 'textbox',
            'hint'    => 'Website'
        ),
        array(
            'display' => 'Industry Type ID',
            'name'    => 'paytm_industry_type_id', 
            'value'   => '',
            'type'    => 'textbox',
            'hint'    => 'Industry Type ID'
        ),
        array(
            'display' => 'Channel ID',
            'name'    => 'paytm_channel_id',
            'value'   => '',
            'type'    => 'textbox',
            'hint'    => 'Channel ID e.g. WEB/WAP'
        ),
        array(
            'display' => 'Mode',
            'name'    => 'paytm_mode',
            'value'   => 'TEST',
            'values'  => array('TEST'=>'TEST','LIVE'=>'LIVE'),
            'type'    => 'select',
            'hint'    => 'Change the mode of the payments'
        ),
```

I am slightly confused that which is the correct method?
Or if anyone above is obsolete?

I am a new comer please bear with me. Thanks
Richa sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd example isn't a different type of setting, it's just an array of data that the plugin will probably *turn into* settings somewhere else in the code. I can't tell from just this code exactly what type of settings it will use or how it does that.

The *actual* two types of settings are the [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/), and the [Customize API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/). Your first block of code is using the Settings API.

The Settings API should be used for back-end admin settings pages. The Customize API should be used for adding settings for things that are visible on the front-end.

For theme options specifically, the wordpress.org theme repository requires use of the Customize API, and not the Settings API.

Another thing to consider is that 3rd-party plugins might have their own APIs for adding settings to them. WooCommerce, for example, has its own way of adding settings to the WooCommerce settings pages (although under the hood it's just the Settings API). Your 2nd block of code *might* be intended for use in the WooCommerce API.

Comment: Actually I was thinking why the second one is not using `add_settings_field(`

Comment: And I explained why. It’s not using anything. All you posted is an array of data. The settings actually being added must happen somewhere else in the codebase, and probably does use `add_settings_field()`.

Comment: I was studying [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paytm-pay/), but couldn't find this any where: `add_settings_field()`

Comment: Then it’s not using the WordPress APIs. You would need to ask it’s deverloper how and why it’s doing it the way it’s doing it. Like I said, some plugins might do things their own way. This is almost always a bad idea. Especially if you’re just starting out.

Comment: They are [registering settings](https://www.screencast.com/t/gFRtEPvbQ). Is it possible that `add_settings_field()` is not necessary? what is the connection between `register settings` and `add_settings_field()`

Comment: WordPress is just PHP, so it’s perfectly possible to handle forms, add form fields, and save to the database  in pretty much any way you want. So no, you don’t *need* to use those functions. But you probably shouldn’t do your own thing. Just use one of the APIs I linked and don’t obsess over what one random plugin is doing.